# Where to put a singleton websocket client in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

When using Electron where is the best place to put a websocket client of which there needs to be a single instance?

It will write received data to local storage. And needs to be able to send messages from renderer threads.

I am unsure of how these requirements would look like.  Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the websocket in the main process and IPC with the renderers.  However this is messy and brittle. Avoid if you can.

Instead, it seems like the best way to go about this is a shared web worker running the websocket.  If you do need to communicate back to the main electron process you can use IPC, but chances are its not to communicate every message from the websocket but rather some more granular action.

```
    if (!!window.SharedWorker) {
        const myWorker = new SharedWorker("worker.ts")

        // For message back from ws we post to local storage and therefore
        // don't need to wire anything here.

        myWorker.port.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log("Message received from worker");
            console.log(e.lastEventId, e.data);
        }

        // All we need for now is a message to make sure its started.
        myWorker.port.postMessage('start')

    }
```

worker.ts

```
interface SharedWorkerGlobalScope {
    onconnect: (event: MessageEvent) => void;
}

const _self: SharedWorkerGlobalScope = self as any;

let counter = 0

_self.onconnect = function (e) {
    var port = e.ports[0]

    port.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log('Worker Received', e.data)
        port.postMessage(`Result ${counter}`)
        counter++
    })

    port.start() // Required when using addEventListener. Otherwise called implicitly by onmessage setter.
}
```

This will result in the counter getting incremented by each call to the shared worker from any electron window you choose.